advanced logic with groupby, apply and transform - compare row value with previous value and create new column
I have the following pandas dataframe:
d= {'Time': [0,1,2,0,1,2,2,3,4], 'Price': ['Auction', 'Auction','800','900','By Negotiation','700','250','250','Make Offer'],'Item': ['Picasso', 'Picasso', 'Picasso', 'DaVinci', 'DaVinci', 'DaVinci', 'Dali', 'Dali', 'Dali']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

I would like to create a fourth column 'Listing-history' which would specify the following:

'first seen' if the listing is seen for the first time (this is not necessarily Time == 0)
'ongoing listing' if there is no change to the price field from one timepoint to the next
'Price->Auction' if the price field changes from a numeric value (which is actually encoded as a string in my dataframe) to the 'Auction' string, and vice versa if the price changes from a numeric value to the 'Auction' string.
I would like the code to be agnostic to the exact price field string, for example: 'Price->By Negotiation' if the price field changes from a numeric value to 'By Negotiation'

I want to group by Item, and then apply the above logic.
Finding whether a listing is 'first seen' is pretty straight forward using something like the following:
df['Price_coerced_to_numeric'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Price'], errors='coerce')
df['Price_diff'] = df.groupby(['Item'])['Price_coerced_to_numeric'].diff(1)

I suspect there is a way of using pandas apply and transform but I haven't been able to work it out. Any tips much appreciated.

Can you have NaNs in the price column?

Also, do you really need to use grouby.transform? This is several orders of magnitude slower than my vectorial approach if you have a very large DataFrame with many items.

You could use groupby.shift and numpy.select:
# replace numbers by "Price"
price = df['Price'].mask(pd.to_numeric(df['Price'], errors='coerce')
                           .notna(), 'Price')
# get previous price
prev_price = price.groupby(df['Item']).shift()

# identify first row per Item
m1 = ~df['Item'].duplicated()
# identify change in price
m2 = price.ne(prev_price)

# combine conditions
df['Listing-history'] = np.select([m1, m2],
                                  ['first seen', prev_price+'->'+price],
                                  'ongoing listing')

Output:
   Time           Price     Item        Listing-history
0     0         Auction  Picasso             first seen
1     1         Auction  Picasso        ongoing listing
2     2             800  Picasso         Auction->Price
3     0             900  DaVinci             first seen
4     1  By Negotiation  DaVinci  Price->By Negotiation
5     2             700  DaVinci  By Negotiation->Price
6     2             250     Dali             first seen
7     3             250     Dali        ongoing listing
8     4      Make Offer     Dali      Price->Make Offer

If you really want to use groupby.transform you code refactor the code a bit:
def history(col):
    price = col.mask(pd.to_numeric(col, errors='coerce').notna(), 'Price')
    prev_price = price.shift()
    return ((prev_price+'->'+price)
            .where(price.ne(prev_price), 'ongoing listing')
            .fillna('first seen') 
           )

df['Listing-history'] = df.groupby('Item')['Price'].transform(history)

variant if you can have NaNs in the original column:
def history(col):
    price = col.mask(pd.to_numeric(col, errors='coerce').notna(), 'Price')
    prev_price = price.shift()
    out = (prev_price+'->'+price).where(price.ne(prev_price), 'ongoing listing')
    out.iat[0] = 'first seen'
    return out

df['Listing-history'] = df.groupby('Item')['Price'].transform(history)


This seems to work. The transform version is more intuitive to me but I agree it is surprisingly slow on my large dataset. I'm trying to work out how your first method works. There's a small caveat in my dataset, I need to group by multiple columns e.g. price.groupby(df['Item','Location']).shift() but this breaks your solution for some reason. I've never used groupby with an object - usually i pass a list of columns... I guess I could group by multiple columns and create a new 'unique-id' column, then apply your solution
